# iOS 7 settings like DetailViewController

Tags: ios7, uitableview

I have a simple project that was started from a Master/Detail template for iOS7.

I'd like to layout the detail view controller just like iOS settings.  Do folks recommend using a table for that or just laying out the controls one by one?

Here is a screenshot of the effect I am looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a matter of taste/opinion but I prefer tables for this kind of thing for these reasons:

1. You get all the nice features of tables right out of the box (efficient scrolling, cell reuse and delegate methods to handle where to push new view controllers on to the stack, etc...).
2. Flexible data model backed cell data. Your table view needs to be backed by some "settings" model object collection, obviously. That collection can be modified to include or exclude settings programmatically. Combine this with custom cells and you're off and rolling. This is really nice if your UI needs to change on the fly.
3. Code Reuse. If you have another set of "settings" you can use this data-backed table view approach and change only your data model. Doing this manually means you have a new view controller for every settings view. In your example picture, I'd bet my lunch that the 3 view controllers you see in that image are the same type of object.
4. The table's delegate methods are really helpful when segueing or pushing to new view controllers. Imagine having 10 settings that all took you to separate view controllers. You'd have to manually hook those transitions one by one, yuck.

Of course if you only have 1-2 settings that will never change, perhaps manual is the way to go. For my money, though, tables make sense because things like this *always* seem to change.

Comment: Aaron, do you usually layout tables statically or do you generate tables dynamically?  I am trying to display a detail view for a managed object and I found that it's easies to just layout the text boxes within the table, but it might be short term thinking.

Comment: @mikebz by "layout tables statically" I'm going to assume you mean by laying them out in Interface Builder. If that's the case, yes. I just hook up a `UITableView` or `UITableViewController` up in IB and that's it. I guess with Storyboards and custom `UITableViewCells` you could pull off something similar to my suggestion AND get a design-time layout in IB.